How to correctly use INCLUDE and WHERE on SQL Server indexes?
Consider this SQL Server query. MyBigTable has ~ 15M rows.
declare @date1 int = 45442;    -- numeric representation for '2024-06-01'
declare @date2 int = 45471;    -- numeric representation for '2024-06-30'
declare @customerID int = 123;

select min(PrimaryKeyId), max(PrimaryKeyId)
from MyBigTable
where 
   NumericDate >= @date1  
   and NumericDate <= @date2 
   and CustomerID = @customerID
   and SoftDeleted = 0         -- avoid "soft deleted" rows; 'SoftDeleted' is BIT

What would be the most efficient index for this query?
I have tried:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyBigTable_Custom1] ON [MyBigTable] (
    [NumericDate] ASC
    [CustomerID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([PrimaryKeyId],[SoftDeleted])
WHERE [SoftDeleted]=0

... plus a few variations... but SQL always chooses another very large index, including several columns not used for this query (even after clearing the plan cache).
I can't have a clustered columnstore index, because this table has computed columns. I have tried a nonclustered columnstore index, including these four fields (NumericDate, CustomerID, PrimaryKeyId and SoftDeleted), but it is also not being used on the query plan.
What criteria should I adopt to decide which fields to include in the indexed columns or in the index's INCLUDE clause? Any other suggestions?
UPDATE:
Data distribution on the table: 1,000 customers, with 6 years of data (some of them started later). This table has one row for each customer x person x date.

To read exactly the required rows for the WHERE clause you need the equality columns before the range column. With NumericDate, CustomerID the best you can get is a range seek on the date and a residual predicate on  CustomerID. With CustomerID,NumericDate it can take advantage of the fact that for a specific CustomerID the rows are ordered by NumericDate and just seek the exact range needed. (The = on SoftDeleted is already implied by the filtered index predicate so is not needed as a key column though should be added as an included column due to issues with unneeded lookups)

@MartinSmith, the data is not necessarily ordered by date, as we often have retroactive data added. However, I understand your point, and it should be useful in other scenarios. Thanks for your comment.

if the date column is the second  key column in  the index then it will be logically ordered by that for each customerid. So will work fine for the range seek. Your additional information doesn’t change that.

Since there are ~1000 customers, the predicate on CustomerID should return roughly 0.1% of the data in the table.  Since there are ~72 months worth of data, the predicate on NumericDate should return roughly 1.4% of the data.  In general, you would want the most selective column to be the leading column of the index.  So my starting point would be this (assuming there is a clustered primary key on PrimaryKeyID, it is not necessary to include that column).
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyBigTable_Custom1] ON [MyBigTable] (
    [CustomerID] ASC,
    [NumericDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([SoftDeleted])
WHERE [SoftDeleted]=0


Most selective only applies to equality predicates (eg CustomerID), because the compiler can only utilize one inequality or range predicates (eg NumericDate) on the index. So all equality predicates first, then join predicates (if any) then range predicates, then inequality predicates. The filtered index is a good idea, if the index never needs to be used for the none SoftDeleted rows.
